# FileUpload.HasFile properties is not within UpdatePanel but still alway return false

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, controls, return

I face this problem for a few day, after searching on google is still not help. Anyone help fix it. my fileupload control is not placed in updatepanel but it' hasFile properties still alway return false.

Here is my code

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            Name
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 5px;">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="error01"
                    ErrorMessage="This field is required !" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            Position
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 5px;">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" CssClass="error01"
                    ErrorMessage="This field is required !" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPosition"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Vietnamese Position
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPositionVN" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 5px;">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" CssClass="error01"
                    ErrorMessage="This field is required !" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPositionVN"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Order
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrder" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="150px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            Email
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 5px;">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" CssClass="error01"
                    ErrorMessage="This field is required !" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" CssClass="text01" Display="Dynamic" 
                ErrorMessage="Input valid email address !" 
                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            Mobile Phone Number
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 5px;">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" CssClass="error01"
                    ErrorMessage="This field is required !" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtPhone" CssClass="text01" Display="Dynamic" 
                ErrorMessage="Input valid mobile phone number !" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;vertical-align: top;">
            Address
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" Width="500px" CssClass="text01" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200px" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            Image
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fupImage" runat="server" CssClass="text01" Width="400px" />
            <asp:Image ID="imgURL" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" Visible="false" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessageForfupImage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td />
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="text01" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"
                CssClass="text01" Visible="False" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" 
                CssClass="text01" CausesValidation="False" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"
                CssClass="text01" Height="22px" CausesValidation="False" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And Code Behind :

```
if (fupImage.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            if (!Utitlties.Instance.CheckImageFileType(fupImage.PostedFile.FileName))
            {
                lblMessageForfupImage.Visible = true;
                lblMessageForfupImage.Text = "Image file only accept *.jpg, *.png, *.bmp, *.gif Extensions !";
                fupImage.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                evt.ImageURL = Utils.Instance.SaveImage(fupImage.PostedFile.InputStream, fupImage.PostedFile.FileName, true);
                UniqueDesign.Utilities.Utitlties.Instance.DeleteFile(imgURL.ImageUrl);
            }
        }
```

when i debbuged it, it's HasFile properties return alway is false, and

fupImage.PostedFile.ContentLength = -2 but it still got filename and filetype.

And here is my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
        A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
        machine.config.comments usually located in 
        \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->

```
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings/>
<!--<location path="admin_ServicesPhotosManager.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="40960" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"/>
    </system.web>
</location>-->
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600"
                             maxRequestLength="40960"
                             minFreeThreads="8"
                             minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
                             appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
                             enableKernelOutputCache="true"
                             enableVersionHeader="true"
                             requireRootedSaveAsPath="true"
                             enable="true"
                             shutdownTimeout="90"
                             delayNotificationTimeout="5"
                             waitChangeNotification="0"
                             maxWaitChangeNotification="0"
                             enableHeaderChecking="true"
                             sendCacheControlHeader="true"
                             apartmentThreading="false"/>
    <!-- 
                    Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
                    symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
                    affects performance, set this value to true only 
                    during development.
            -->
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="FileUploadLibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=AF961ECE0B692DFB"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
                    The <authentication> section enables configuration 
                    of the security authentication mode used by 
                    ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
            -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
                    The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
                    of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
                    during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
                    it enables developers to configure html error pages 
                    to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
                    <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                    <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            </customErrors>
            -->
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="GET" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.UploadProgressHandler, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb" path="UploadProgress.ashx"/>
        <add verb="GET" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.SQLFileDownloadHandler, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb" path="DownloadFile.ashx"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="upload_module" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.UploadModule, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<!-- 
            The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
            Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824">
            </requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <remove name="upload_module" />
        <add name="upload_module" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.UploadModule, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UploadProgress" verb="GET" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.UploadProgressHandler, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb" path="UploadProgress.ashx" />
        <add name="FileDownload" verb="GET" type="darrenjohnstone.net.FileUpload.SQLFileDownloadHandler, fileuploadlibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af961ece0b692dfb" path="DownloadFile.ashx" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: hi abe , i edited my post. thanks for your concern. hope we can fix it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I had this problem and figured I'd post what my problem and solution were as well.

**Make sure the file you are trying to upload is larger than 0 bytes.** I was trying to upload some blank text files for testing and each file had the `FileName` property set correctly, but `HasFile` was always false. Adding some text to the files gave it some content and the file was able to be uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is your UpdatePanel then?  Are you trying to submit a form that is within an updatepanel, but also has a fileupload control which is not?

I don't think that will work either.

You can use the AJAX control toolkit version of FileUpload, or use something else such as Uploadify which is a jquery plugin.

Comment: Hi jack, thanks for your response but i dont use any UpdatePanel in my website, i edit my post with adding my code.

Comment: i think reason is i'm using darren's FileUPloadLibrary, when i tested my web without darren's control , it work fine.